# How to install plugins conditionally based on platform using gulp?

Tags: gulp

I want to install a plugin only for android and not for ios platform. I want to do it using gulp, so I have created a gulp task for it and used platformify().filter(["android"]). Following is my code snippet but it doesn't work for me.Plugin gets added to both platforms. Not sure I have implemented it right. So any help will be appreciated.

```
gulp.task('InstallImageResizerPlugin',function(){
     platformify().filter(["android"],sh.exec('cordova plugin add https://github.com/wymsee/cordova-imageResizer', {async: true},     function(code, output){}));
```